# Inserting data from .csv file using Oracle's external tables

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-loader, external-tables

I want to insert data from .csv file to my table. Can I do it with organization external and oracle_loader or do I need to do something else?

```
SQL>       create table teachers_ext (
      2        first_name     varchar2(15),
      3        last_name      varchar2(15),
      4        phone_number   varchar2(12)
      5      )
      6      organization external (
      7        type oracle_loader
      8        default directory ext_data_files
      9        access parameters (
     10         fields terminated by ',')
     11       location ('teacher.csv')
     12     )
     13     reject limit unlimited;
```

Comment: As in http://www.orafaq.com/node/848 ?

Comment: If you're using PL/SQL Developer, the best way is to use the "Text Importer" tool.

Comment: I today only uploaded csv file to oracle table Using **SQL LOADER** in Oracle to import CSV file.  Check out this [link](http://steve-lyon.blogspot.com/2013/07/sql-loader-step-by-step-basics-example-1.html)

Comment: *"Can i do it with organization external and oracle_loader "* Yes and yes. So what happens when you create your external table and then select from it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is the best way to do it.
But I suppose that if you are asking is because it doesn´t work.

May be is a permission problem (you can´t use ext_data_files directory for example).

Do you get an error when you try to create your external table?

Do you get an error when you try SELECT from it?